# Python: how to get sum of values based on different columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a datframe `df` like the following:

```
df  name     city
0   John    New York
1   Carl    New York
2   Carl     Paris
3   Eva      Paris
4   Eva      Paris
5   Carl     Paris
```

I want to know the total number of people in the different cities

```
df2  city      number
0   New York     2
1    Paris       3
```

or the number of people with the same name in the cities

```
df2    name     city      number
0      John    New York     1
1      Eva      Paris       2
2      Carl     Paris       2
3      Eva      New York    0
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe need [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby(['city']).size().reset_index(name='number')
print (df1)
       city  number
0  New York       2
1     Paris       4
```

---

```
df2 = df.groupby(['name','city']).size().reset_index(name='number')
print (df2)
   name      city  number
0  Carl  New York       1
1  Carl     Paris       2
2   Eva     Paris       2
3  John  New York       1
```

If need all combinations one solution is add `unstack` and `stack`:

```
df3=df.groupby(['name','city']).size().unstack(fill_value=0).stack().reset_index(name='count')
print (df3)
   name      city  number
0  Carl  New York       1
1  Carl     Paris       2
2   Eva  New York       0
3   Eva     Paris       2
4  John  New York       1
5  John     Paris       0
```

Or [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) with [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
df2 = df.groupby(['name','city']).size()
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df2.index.levels, names=df2.index.names)
df2 = df2.reindex(mux, fill_value=0).reset_index(name='number')
print (df2)
   name      city  number
0  Carl  New York       1
1  Carl     Paris       2
2   Eva  New York       0
3   Eva     Paris       2
4  John  New York       1
5  John     Paris       0
```

Answer (score 0):

To count the number of people with different names in the same city:

```
groups = df.groupby('city').count().reset_index()
```

To count the number of people with the same name in different cities:

```
groups = df.groupby('city').count().reset_index()
```